# Program for HID USB Scale

Tags: excel, usb, hid

I'm looking for a program that can read the weight on a USB scale, namely the Pelouze 10lb USB Portable Scale. I thought it would have a virtual COM port driver but instead, it uses HID drivers. I've been searching for a whole month for a program that can help me transfer the reading of the scale to Microsoft Excel. Can someone help me out or point me in the right direction? I am absolutely illiterate to programming. Much gratitude any help given.

Comment: Are you sure the device supports comms over USB, and not just power?

Comment: Here's the link to the product page to the scale
http://global.dymo.com/enUS/Products/10_lb__USB_Mailing_Scale.html

Im pretty sure it does communicate over USB because it came with a software for Stamps.com.  I tried it out and it does show the weight on the PC but i can't export the weigh onto Excel.

Also, i used SimpleHIDWrite.exe and found that it does recognize the scale and shows the weight in what looks like hexadecimal numbers.

Answer (score 6):

I can offer some helpful links.

The scales use the "HID point of sale" USB spec, a link to which can be found in the comments section of the blog post I mention below. I'd link direct, but the spam prevention mechanism prevents me.

There's a blog post on addressing the 25lb version of the scale from C#, here: http://nicholas.piasecki.name/blog/2008/11/reading-a-stamps-com-usb-scale-from-c-sharp/

The comments on that post are helpful - that's where you find the [USB spec](https://www.usb.org/sites/default/files/documents/pos1_02.pdf), there's also a comment showing how to get at the data without using the full HID library.

Good luck with your project!

Comment: That blog entry is very helpful and well written. Unfortunately, the link within the blog is dead. The blog is still worthwhile, though.

Comment: It looks like the HID USB code used in the blog has moved to: https://github.com/mikeobrien/HidLibrary

Comment: Link is broken. Any chance you have the contents of that post around which you could share here??

Answer (score 2):

I wrote some code to read from a Dymo USB scale using Python. It requires libusb and PyUSB.

This code is pretty general; it should work with any HID device that has just one configuration:

```
import usb.core
import usb.util

VENDOR_ID = 0x0922
PRODUCT_ID = 0x8003

# find the USB device
device = usb.core.find(idVendor=VENDOR_ID,
                       idProduct=PRODUCT_ID)

# use the first/default configuration
device.set_configuration()
# first endpoint
endpoint = device[0][(0,0)][0]

# read a data packet
attempts = 10
data = None
while data is None and attempts > 0:
    try:
        data = device.read(endpoint.bEndpointAddress,
                           endpoint.wMaxPacketSize)
    except usb.core.USBError as e:
        data = None
        if e.args == ('Operation timed out',):
            attempts -= 1
            continue

print data
```

For the DYMO M10 scale I'm using, the data packet is a 6-element array like this `array('B', [3, 2, 11, 255, 0, 0])`.

The last two elements are used to calculate the weight.

In kg mode `grams = data[4] + (256 * data[5])`, and in pounds/ounces mode `ounces = 0.1 * (data[4] + (256 * data[5]))`.

More info on [my blog post](http://steventsnyder.com/reading-a-dymo-usb-scale-using-python/).

Answer (score 0):

The first question that you will need to answer is the exact HID use. USB describes a wide family of related protocols. USB HID is a subset, but this still covers a large array of devices. The HID specs defines a 32 bits "usage" identifier supporting up to 4 billion different types of HID devices, although only a fraction of those values have been assigned so far.

The Windows API you'll probably need is [Raw Input](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms645543.aspx). Unfortunately, this is not an interface for the programming illiterate.

Answer (score 0):

For USB devices not supported directly by the O/S, you either need to be a programmer, or you need a program supplied by the device vendor.  In this case, as it sounds like you're not a programmer, you should contact the manufacturer to see if they can provide any diagnostic or testware programs that could be used to read and capture the scale data.  If you're lucky, such a program can be "batched" and it's output redirected, or something like that.  Good luck.

Answer (score 0):

Elane sells a line of USB HID scales and also has a Windows program to read the weight.  Unfortunately, because of Stamps.com, that program is no longer free.  At $15.50, it's not necessarily something I'd want to blindly try, but here it is:
http://www.elane.net/index.php?go=USB_pcsoftware

Answer (score 0):

if you want to play detective this guy's advice might help :

http://nicholas.piasecki.name/blog/2008/11/reading-a-stamps-com-usb-scale-from-c-sharp/

Just ordered a DYMO scale myself so will post findings

Answer (score 0):

http://r.lagserv.net/scalereader.htm

This is great code to get started with for C# and a Dymo scale using HidLibrary.

Just change the vendor ID to match that of your scale.

You can be up and running in a few minutes.

I used it with a Dymo S400.

Answer (score 0):

I wrote my nodejs version and shared the code at https://github.com/PhantomRay/dymo-scale-nodejs.

It is only tested in Windows 10. Also, it has a simple web socket server mode built to it so that any web page can connect to it to read data.

Comment: I tested the scale in Ubuntu and Mac. It is not recognised as HID device by default. So the code doesn't work in this two OS. Not sure if there is a way to force it as HID device. Maybe some drivers.

Answer (score -3):

I would assume that output from a USB HID device like this should appear to the USB host exactly as if the input was typed on a keyboard, i.e. on the scale stabilising, the weight would be sent over USB.  This is the way most USB barcode scanners work.

If this is the case then the scale should just fire across the weight and it would appear in whatever application was active; Excel if that is where you wanted the input to end up.

However, I've looked over the specs and manual for the scale you specify and, unless I'm looking at the wrong model, although it is powered by USB I don't see any mention of the fact that it also communicates over USB.  Do you have a URL or part number?

Comment: That's certainly not true. A mouse is also a HID device, and that's certainly not a keyboard.

Comment: Very true.  I'm used to dealing with scanners etc, and assumed that a scale would follow the keyboard device profile as it wouldn't make much sense for it to constantly emit a fluctuating reading.

Comment: The fluctuations aren't the problem; the problem is that a scale should produce its reading when the PC wants it. A keyboard and a bar scanner push events towards the PC as they happen.

Comment: That assumes a scale stabilizes. Just put a human on top to see a clear example when it doesn't.

Comment: This is a mailing scale, it will have an indicator to show when the reading is stable.  Our Pitney Bowes equipment prints a label automatically when the device senses a stable load, one simply needs to remove the item and place another to get the next label.  I assumed a much simpler USB device would work in a similar fashion.

Comment: Here are some screenshots of the SimpleHIDWrite program output. Hope this helps.

http://www.freeimagehosting.net/image.php?dc59b02ecc.jpg

http://www.freeimagehosting.net/image.php?2916c4a9a9.jpg

Comment: Have a look at this PDF file from page 27 onwards: http://www.dymo.com/media/UserGuides/HID_POS_USB_Spec.pdf That might help slightly in mapping hex values to behaviours

Comment: haha thanks for the reference but unfortunately, i can't make use of it as i dont know much about programming. =P

Comment: There would also be plenty of moments where the scale is "stabile", depending on the polling period.